# Calcular length de um campo SQLServer

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Olá, tenho uma tabela no SQL com a coluna palavra e uma coluna tamanhoDaPalavra, queria saber se tem alguma forma de cadastrar a palavra no banco e executar uma função que calcule a quantidade de caracteres nesta palavra para salvar na coluna tamanhoDaPalavra?

Comment: como está declarada a coluna tamanhoDaPalavra?

Answer (score 2):

Para verificar a quantidade de caracteres:

```
SELECT LEN(COLUNA) FROM TABELA
```

Para inserir a quantidade de caracteres do VALOR1 na COLUNA2 no momento do insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA (COLUNA1,COLUNA2)
VALUES ('VALOR1',LEN('VALOR1'))
```

Caso queira fazer depois que os dados já foram inseridos:

```
UPDATE TABELA SET COLUNA2 = LEN(COLUNA1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Eduardo, existem duas funções no SQL Server que retornam o tamanho: [Len()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190329.aspx) e [DataLength()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173486.aspx). E, ao consultar a documentação das duas funções, perceberá que há ligeira diferença de comportamento entre elas.

Você pode usar uma [coluna calculada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188300.aspx) para que o tamanho da palavra seja (re)calculado automaticamente.

```
-- código #1
USE tempDB;

CREATE TABLE Dic (
  palavra varchar(20),
  tamanhoDaPalavra as Len(palavra)
);

INSERT into Dic (palavra) values
  ('caminhão'), ('maçã'), ('trevo');

SELECT *
  from Dic; 

DROP TABLE Dic;
```